# Saving JTextArea using Bufferedwriter ignores new line. (Notepad clone)

Tags: java, swing, newline, notepad

I was developing a notepad clone as a fun little side-project, and I came across what I have always come across throughout my short personal career of Java and Swing:

Attempting to save a JTextArea's '.getText()' with plenty of new lines, yields to a text file with all of the text jumbled up into one single line.

**Is there a way for bufferedwriter (correct me if I'm wrong) to automatically create a new line when it detects an 'enter' in the text and create a new line in the saved .txt file?**

(As a side note, I accidentally used a JEditorPane, and this saves the new lines perfectly fine, but my "Open/Import .txt" function no longer works.)

Comment: Use the JTextArea's own `write(...)` method. Pass a BufferedWriter into it and this should create an OS-specific file with correct newline chars.

Comment: @Hover, Apologies, but I'm quite basic in Java compared to others. How exactly could I do this? Should I provide a section of my code?

Comment: No need -- just check the duplicate question used to close this question.

Comment: @Hover - Ahh, thank you. I always feel like I'm posting useless questions, lol.